# Eclipse Blender and PyDev Unresolved import pydevd

Tags: eclipse, pydev, blender

I have python installed at:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32
```

My PATH variable is:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32
```

And I have this in Eclipse:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And finally I have this -.- (you can see that 'import sys' works:

[image]

Comment: You may find some useful info [here](https://code.blender.org/2015/10/debugging-python-code-with-pycharm/). Another option is to compile blender as a [python module](https://en.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) so that you can run the non-gui parts from any python interpreter.

Comment: the idea is to make python code for blender in eclipse, start that code in blender and debug that code in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find what was wrong.
First, it is needed to download module, in this case [pydevd](https://pypi.org/project/pydevd/#files)

Be careful, download not latest (like I did wrong first time) but with version of python it is installed.
In my case it is Python **3.5**.3 so I choose:

pydevd-1.3.0-cp**35**-cp**35**m-win32.whl

Then install it with pip, it is easy:

pip install C:**%where_it_is_downloaded%**/pydevd-1.3.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

Then there will be **pydevd** added to Packages beside **pip** and **setuptools**:

[image]
And one more thing.
Compare this 2 screens. Path to **site-packages** has to be changed from **lib** to **Lib**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a tip, as the debugger is usually only temporarily used, so, you could just use the internal version from PyDev if you're Ok with the `unresolved imports` and just want to connect the remote debugger to Blender.

You could do that by using the `pydevd` template (i.e.: write inside PyDev `pydevd` and press `Ctrl+Space` and the option which would add it to the `PYTHONPATH` and then connect to the remote debugger would appear).

See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html for more details on the remote debugger.